# Please suspend the '20 rep to chat' rule just for our own bh.se chat rooms for the duration of the beta?

Tags: feature-request, chat

We are attracting newcomers with no experience of Stack Exchange, and [The Library](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) is a key tool for helping folk learn the ropes of the format.

Please can we temporarily suspend this rule?

Answer (score 6):

As a moderator, you can exempt folks from this restriction on a case-by-case basis. See: [Allow inviting people with rep < 20 to private chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111942/allow-inviting-people-with-rep-20-to-private-chat/111946#111946) for details.

Exempting an entire room would be asking for trouble, I fear.

Anything you can do to guide folks that *doesn't* require extensive one-on-one support will probably pay off in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the link: I had an idea this was possible, but I fear the bar is too high to be of practical use here. We want a) users who happen to wander in to be able to chat (we don't know who they are so can't manually add them) and b) users we specifically ask into chat with a 'The Library' link in a comment (and adding in the additional step of getting them to log in to chat before we can enable them to post, then getting them back in *again* makes the the whole process improbable with the average professor of theology who happens upon the site from Google).

Comment: What sort of trouble are you worried about btw?

Comment: 20 rep is not a huge barrier, but it's significant enough to prevent a lot of the abuse that becomes instantly possible when anyone can create a new user (or a dozen...) and start chatting. Consider that the various moderation tools in chat mean very little when it doesn't take more than a minute to get a new user created and in the room.

Comment: The truth is, chat was never meant to be a first-class part of the system - more that backroom where folks gather after hours to unwind. Comments are probably more appropriate in at least one of the scenarios you describe - there's a reason new users (regardless of reputation) can always comment on their own posts.

Comment: Good point about comments, I've ben worried about over-using them, perhaps needlessly :)